# Captured camera image is looking blurry

Tags: android, camera

My issue captured image is looking blurry in my application where as the image that is captured with the device camera component is looking good - something auto zoom effect is going once user click on capture button. can some one help me to achieve this scenario how and where should i apply.

here is the code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Integer version = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    if(version > Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "------> version greater than eclari 2.1");
        List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "------> version less than eclari 2.1");
        parameters.setPreviewSize(ApplicationInitiator.screenW,ApplicationInitiator.screenH); 
    }

    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
    {
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, on your text you talk about capturing a image, but I don't see anything in your code about taking a picture, Anyway, if you want to obtain a focused photo, what you have to do is register a AutoFocusCallback to take a picture when focus is obtained:

```
Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallbackRaw);
    }
};

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallbackRaw = new Camera.PictureCallback() {  
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) { 
        // (...)            
    }  
};

public void takeFocusedPicture() {
    mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
}
```

.

Comment: It really works! Thanks a lot. But if you just try to call camera.takePicture you will see blurry surface after that.

Comment: This must be called just right before take a picture, or it won't work.