# Images from Custom Camera are blurry on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy

I have a custom camera in the app and the images that are taken on most of the devices look good but on galaxy nexus the story is different. Images are blurry in Galaxy nexus. I see grainy lines on Motorola Atrix as well. But Droid X, Droid Razr, HTC Evo, HTC incredible are showing good results. Any idea why it would happpen? This is what I have so far. 
P.S.: I am using Auto focus in the activity.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
    // preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }

        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    try {
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you including <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" /> in the manifest?

Comment: YES. I did added it to the manifest file.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838441/captured-camera-image-is-looking-blurry  did you try changing camera.setJpegQuality() ?

Comment: Well, I am getting this behavior just for Galaxy Nexus and Atrix.

Comment: How will setting JPEG quality help me? Unless it has different requirements for Nexus and Atrix

Comment: Did you find a solution to this at all?  We're experiencing a very similar issue with the same phone: Galaxy Nexus.  Been stuck on this for weeks.  Thanks.

Comment: @dazhi: I answered it below, please check it out. Let me know if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Its been a while I solved this problem. If I remember it correctly, I solved by adding the below lines while getting the camera instance.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
int w = 0, h = 0;
for (Size size : sizes) {
   if (size.width > w || size.height > h) {
      w = size.width;
      h = size.height;
   }

 }
 parameters.setPictureSize(w, h);
```

Comment: where you added those lines?

Comment: This works even today (for older code) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one ?

```
if (cameraParameters.getSupportedSceneModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_STEADYPHOTO)) {
   cameraParameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_STEADYPHOTO);
}
```

Comment: There are people who climb stackoverflow for the sake of collecting coins, and there are people like you who help others. This code works very well! +1 from me