# Android Camera takes blurry Image

Tags: android, android-camera

Working on an app to auto capture the objects, But I'm getting blurry photos as shown in below. It works fine with ICS. But when I tested with Nexus 7, I got an half-blurred image. I have no clue why does it happen. Any suggestion to avoid this blurry effect? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943800/images-from-custom-camera-are-blurry-on-galaxy-nexus

Comment: Yes, that is not not the right solution

Comment: probably you are not using camera's suggested and supported resolutions.

Comment: As far as I know I haven't given any particular resolution in code, to capture the image